# Not able to select dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery

I have this issue, I searched but can't find an answer. I'm creating the below code dynamically:

```
$("#addQuad").popover({
placement : 'bottom',
title : 'Title',
html:true,
content : '$htm',
template: '<div class="popover add_quad_popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div   class="popover-inner"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
});
```

## QuadVenueSearch is in my $htm variable, for the life of me I can't access this element. How do I proceed and somehow add this element to the DOM?

```
$("#QuadVenueSearch").typeahead({

  source: function (query, process) {

  $.ajax({
  url: QuadzerObj.APP_PATH + "venues/typeahead_search",
  type: "get",
  data: {query: query},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    venues = [];  
    map = {};

     $.each(data, function(index, venue){
              map[venue.name] = venue;
              venues.push(venue.name);
      });
   process(venues);
  }
});
},
 updater: function(item) {
     $("#QuadVenueID").val(map[item].id);
      return item;
}
});
```

I tried to bind them by doing this, but still not working:

```
$('html').bind('bindQPS',function(){
$("#QuadVenueSearch").typeahead({

 source: function (query, process) {

 $.ajax({
 url: QuadzerObj.APP_PATH + "venues/typeahead_search",
 type: "get",
 data: {query: query},
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
 venues = [];  
 map = {};

 $.each(data, function(index, venue){
              map[venue.name] = venue;
              venues.push(venue.name);
      });
   process(venues);
  }
});
},
updater: function(item) {
     $("#QuadVenueID").val(map[item].id);
      return item;
}
});
});

$("#addQuad").popover({
placement : 'bottom',
title : 'Title',
html:true,
content : '$htm',
template: '<div class="popover add_quad_popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div  class="popover-inner"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div>   </div>'}).trigger('bindQPS');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for an answer to this question, here's how I solved it:

```
$('body').on('focus','#QuadVenueSearch',function(e){  

  $(this).typeahead({

  source: function (query, process) {
  $.ajax({
  url: QuadzerObj.APP_PATH + "venues/typeahead_search",
  type: "get",
  data: {query: query},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    venues = [];  
    map = {};
     $.each(data, function(index, venue){
              map[venue.name] = venue;
              venues.push(venue.name);
      });
   process(venues);
  }
});
},
updater: function(item) {
     $("#QuadVenueID").val(map[item].id);
      return item;
     }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The element "`#QuadVenueSearch`" does NOT exist on page when you are trying to access it.
It will be created after you call `$("#addQuad").popover('show')` (or something similar to show the popup).

Try calling `$("#QuadVenueSearch").typeahead()` after the popup is displayed.

Hope this will help.

Comment: The way I think I can accomplish this is by binding them, but it isn't working.